# android access Service method from Activity onCreate

Tags: android, android-service

I want to access my service method and I found a way to do that but I have a problem with it. Let's see the code first.

The service:

```
public class Notification_Intent_Service extends IntentService {

    private final static String TAG = "Service";

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public static Socket client;

    public Notification_Intent_Service() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public Notification_Intent_Service getServerInstance() {
            return Notification_Intent_Service.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

     try {


        client = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.106:3000/",opts);

            client.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    }

}
```

In the service there is a socket I want to access from Activity and emit some data, this is my Activity:

```
Notification_Intent_Service mServer;

ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Toast.makeText(call_video.this, "Service is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = false;
        mServer = null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Toast.makeText(call_video.this, "Service is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = true;
        LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
        mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();

        }

    };

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mServer.client.emit("balabala","JSONmessage");

   }
```

We can see I use:

> mServer.client.emit("balabala","JSONmessage");

when the Activity is created but when I use the mServer it shows an error because it's still null so I must use it inside

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Toast.makeText(call_video.this, "Service is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = true;
        LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
        mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();

       //here use it
        }
```

but this also gives me some problems. I see some of the Views in Activity are still null when I use it. So my question is, how can I access the service from Activity onCreate 
or is there are another way to do it (like to create a new connection to a socket) that might be better than this?

Comment: `IntentService`  is not a good choice for service to bind ... even more ... you **never** should bind `IntentService`

Comment: @Selvin so access IntentService bad way or only  bind IntentService only

Comment: you should rather use normal `Service` with it own thread ... `IntentService `is for: do `onHandleIntent` and die ... and about the question you should not use it in onCreate - `//here use it` is a good place ... *i see some of View* that's not clear ...

Comment: @Selvin but i use BroadcastReceiver  with it is thats good or must i change it

Comment: @Selvin some of View that's not clear i mean some **button** or **ImageView**
still null when i use it in `//here use it`

Comment: BroadcastReceiver? where ... If you dont need RPC LocalBinder is ok

Comment: *some of View that's not clear i mean some button or ImageView still null when i use it* ... still not clear ... you should do in `onCreate() { setContentView(); obtainViews(); startService(); bindService(); }` ... i would even move `startService(); bindService();` to `onResume` and add `undbindService();` in `onPause`

Comment: @Selvin ok thats good about my **BroadcastReceiver**  i didnt share it i will share it if you want just tell me this now good idea and i still on _IntentService and bind Service_ it or i must change it i tell you i use **BroadcastReceiver** with it